# LEFT JOIN not working when comparing the date between two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

Here i am doing cab allocation module,here i will explain my requirement,admin allocate the cab to the employees in shift wise.this details i stored in cab_allocation allocation table.

> cab_allocation (Table Name)

```
allocationId        from_allocationDate       to_allocationdate       cabId    shiftTiming

1                   2017-09-08                 2017-09-30             CBX100     1
2                   2017-09-08                 2017-09-30             CBX100     2
```

after this i want to track this trip is happening every day or not, for this tracking details i stored in trip_details table

> trip_details (table name)

```
id      allocationId   tripDate   startTime   endTime      tripStatus

 1             1       2017-09-08  09:30:00    11:30:00       1
 2             2       2017-09-08  12.10.00    02:30:00       1
 3             1       2017-09-09  12.10.00                   0
```

yesterday(2017-09-08) allocationId 1 & 2 trip has completed(tripStatus 1 means completed), and today(2017-09-09) allocationId 1 trip has started but not yet completed(tripStatus 0 means not completed, like ongoing the trip) and today(2017-09-09) allocationId 2 trip it seems not started so there is no entry in trip_details table.

> Now what i want means today howmany allocation is there i need that details from cab_allocation table based cabId, Suppose today that trip is completed means trip details should not display, Suppose today trip is not completed means i want display the details.

**I tried like this **

```
SELECT a.allocationId, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId 
FROM cab_allocation a 
LEFT JOIN trip_details b ON a.allocationId = b.allocationId 
WHERE a.cabId='CBX100' AND b.tripStatus != '1' AND a.from_allocationDate >= '2017-09-09' AND a.to_allocationdate <= '2017-09-09'
```

But i am getting no results found,but based on my table structure i need output like this

```
    {
"status": "success",
"count": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "allocationId": "1",
        "shiftTiming": "1",
    },
    {
        "allocationId": "2",
        "shiftTiming": "2",
    }
]
}
```

> My Updated Code

```
SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId 
FROM cab_allocation a 
LEFT JOIN trip_details b ON a.allocationId = b.allocationId 
WHERE a.cabId='CBX100' AND b.tripStatus != '1' AND a.from_allocationDate <= '2017-09-09' AND
  a.to_allocationdate >= '2017-09-09'
```

Comment: Your sample data and your query have different columns.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, please check now my query and sample data is same

Comment: any one is there? as per knowledge i am thinking today allocation id 2  trip it self not started , so there is no entry in trip_details because this allocation id 2 details we are getting, how we can solve this

Comment: Seems you do not understand comparisons with null and/or left join. It is inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. You cannot mean that you want `left join` *and* `where b.x != '1'` because for that to be so b.x cannot be null so you cannot return any of the null-extended rows so you cannot need left join but just need inner join. Your writing in your post & comments is unclear, please use more sentences & words. Try translate.google.com, it is lately far better via AI. Why is that "updated code" there? Please be clear.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't want a `left join` for this.  Use `inner join`.  Your intention is to do filtering.

Second, your `where` clause is:

```
WHERE a.cabId='CBX100' AND b.tripStatus <> '1' AND
      a.from_allocationDate >= '2017-09-09' AND
      a.to_allocationdate <= '2017-09-09'
```

You have the conditions on the dates backwards.  You want:

```
WHERE a.cabId='CBX100' AND b.tripStatus <> '1' AND
      a.from_allocationDate <= '2017-09-09' AND
      a.to_allocationdate >= '2017-09-09'
```

The from date needs to be *before* the to date.

Comment: @ I tried your code but i am getting results,MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Comment: SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId 
    FROM cab_allocation a 
    INNER JOIN trip_details b ON a.allocationId = b.allocationId 
    WHERE a.cabId='CBX100' AND b.tripStatus <> '1' AND
      a.from_allocationDate >= '2017-09-09' AND
      a.to_allocationdate <= '2017-09-09'

Comment: I tried this sql query but ,it showing empty result,you tested this code it is working fine for you?

Comment: Please see my updated sql query, i tried like that means it is one result(allocationId 1), but actual result come two

Comment: are you there? as per knowledge i  am thinking today allocation id 2 trip it self not started , so there is no entry in trip_details because this allocation id 2 details we are getting, how we can solve this